# How to repair a microwave door with a broken spot weld

Tags: appliances, microwave-oven

My microwave door slacks down and I have to lift it up a bit before shutting it. I sent this picture to Frigidaire and asked what I should do:

[image]

Their support emailed me back saying:

> I'm sorry, there is no screw that goes in the hole. that actually is a
>   broken spot weld for the hinge. The hinge cannot be repaired.

Here's a short video of the issue:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMWu6HFAwN0&feature=youtu.be

I want to fix the issue without replacing my entire microwave. Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Looks like the door still works to me. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

**Don't do it.**

Microwaves, while safe, emit a significant radiation that is controlled, in part, by a carefully designed door interlock system. If it is compromised, there is a risk of radiation leakage.

You don't fix microwave doors, you send it back for them to fix or you replace the entire unit.

**Period**.

**SUPPLEMENT**

The [World Health Organization](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/info_microwaves/en/) (WHO) has this to say about microwave oven safety.

> Microwave safety: The design of microwave ovens ensures that the microwaves are contained within the oven and can only be present when the oven is switched on and the door is shut. Leakage around and through the glass door is limited by design to a level well below that recommended by international standards. However, microwave leakage could still occur around damaged, dirty or modified microwave ovens. It is therefore important that the oven is maintained in good condition. Users should check that the door closes properly and that the safety interlock devices, fitted to the door to prevent microwaves from being generated while it is open, work correctly. The door seals should be kept clean and there should be no visible signs of damage to the seals or the outer casing of the oven. **If any faults are found or parts of the oven are damaged, it should not be used until it has been repaired by an appropriately qualified service engineer** [emphasis added].

The [US Food and Drug Administration](http://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm048953.htm) (FDA) says this

> Checking For Leakage: There is little cause for concern about excess microwaves leaking from ovens **unless the door hinges, latch, or seals are damaged**. If you suspect a problem, contact the oven manufacturer, a microwave oven service organization, your state health department, or the closest FDA office [emphasis added].

The problem described is not just tightening a screw or putting a seal back in its track. The door is misaligned and poses a risk. Trying to realign and weld parts of the safety system seems very ill-advised.

Comment: Can you describe the interlock system and why there is risk of radiation leakage?

Comment: the microwave enclosure acts as a faraday cage, isolating the inside RF radiation from the outside

Comment: @ratchetfreak, If I understand you, you are saying that the hinge mechanism is not important to the safe operation of the microwave, so long as the door is closed flush to the opening?

Comment: @Edwin Warnings from health organizations have been added to the answer.

Comment: @bib I have got to admit, your Appeal to Authority (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) pushes my buttons.  But you haven't shown any evidence why it would be dangerous if the OP fixed his own hinge.  Maybe we should focus on how the OP could safely fix his microwave. This isn't the Don't Do it Yourself forum.

Comment: @Edwin Respectfully disagree. I am pretty game to try projects involving a wide range of risks. Also don't think that we have to follow a manufacturer's admonition of *no user serviceable parts* . Some things carry risks that just aren't worth it if an error can be catastrophic (e.g. serious gas installations by someone with no experience). Microwaves have been largely tamed, but a leak would be bad. The cost of replacement is often less than $100. I think the risk/reward ratio is poor. Also, i think that this site should not advocate activities that are  high risk to a non-expert audience.

Comment: @bib What I don't understand is why you think that fixing the hinge on a microwave would be dangerous.  What is the underlying danger here?  I have done a little research into the matter and see little risk, especially in comparison to a mundane and common risk like driving a car.

Comment: If the hinge is not fixed *correctly*, you risk leaking microwaves and heating things outside the enclosure. Injury and/or fire are possible, and you may have little or no warning. I don't mind violating "no user servicable parts", but it has to be done with a decent understanding of the hazards involved and how to control them. I tend to agree that the risk here outweighs the possible savings, given how cheap microwave ovens are these days, and definitely exceeds the DIY egoboo opportunities.

Comment: This answer is mostly hyperbole, fear, uncertainty, and doubt.  If the door is fixed reasonably well, it cures all the dangers, especially in comparison to the existing situation.  With my first microwave oven (1983) came a free 9 hour microwave class.  The instructor demonstrated that the hole in the Faraday cage had to be huge (6-8 cm) before any appreciable radiation energy passed through it.  This is something anyone can test using perforated aluminum foil wrapped around chocolate or whatever.

Comment: @wallyk There are all levels of skill when it comes to repairs, and many of our readers would have the ability to tackle this safely. But there are some things, if screwed up, have very dangerous consequences. Having a rank amateur handle a main electrical panel is a bad idea. While the risks of microwaves leaking are small. If there were a compromise of the door seals, there is a risk, albeit small, of a very bad exposure, especially with prolonged exposure near the device. It's hard to control for level of skill, pattern of use. Better safe than sorry. You are free to disagree and answer.

Comment: @wallyk, in the last twenty years we've all learned a lot more about microwaves than we knew in the 1980s. One thing we've learned is that it takes far less microwave energy to give you cataracts and eventually blind you than it takes to melt a foil-wrapped chocolate bar.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it with a small screw, washer, and nut. On my Frigidaire microwave, the hole does go through both the door frame and the hinge piece. I had to pick a screw with a shallow head.

Now, several years later, the metal at that point is beginning to crack, and the door is sagging again. I am not sure what to do, but I did lengthen the life of the microwave.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your video how the hinge works.  It probably works like the top hinge.   If it is simply attached to the front like the "broken weld" suggests, then your goal would be to reattach it.  My go-to for this would be a steel rivet.  If you don't have a handheld riveter, I highly recommend getting one.  They come in handy.  Though, if there is no existing hole in the hinge part, it might be impractical to make a hole to accommodate the rivet while the microwave is assembled.  Bare in mind that disassembling the microwave would make some on this site uneasy.  I say use your common sense. If you feel uncomfortable or that you're not up to it, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem. 6-32 screw from the outside and a nut on the inside.  I was unable to get it off the wall so I just removed the screws that hold the bottom on and fixed it from underneath.

Comment: This says **what** you used to fix it, but not **how** you fixed it. Please update your post with some more details, including some photographs. This would make it a much more useful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as James without having seen this thread.  The screw used must be a  flathead type so that it does not protrude from the front of the microwave chassis and interfere with door closure.